# Change values in array to a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Just wondering, what is the best way to go about "sorting" an array to the following:

I have the array as [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], how would I sort it so it goes:

[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]

I cannot think of the phrase or a method to do this.

This is done in angularjs/can use jquery.

Comment: Angular and jQuery to sort an array? Why not use `.sort()`?

Comment: Is the starting array always half and half like your example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: So split in half and interweave? Doubt you want to sort.

Comment: evolutionxbox, Yoda sorting an re-arranging are different. TylerWilson you probably want to simply loop from both ends and append values one at a time

Comment: @AlekseySolovey indeed. OP needs to give more examples of their issue, and the desired output.

Comment: I think that OP's "sort" means interleave.

Comment: does the dupe targets help you?

Comment: I understand now, my mistake